# Declaring field public vs private with public accessor lwc child component

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I need to pass a parameter from the parent component to a child in lwc. Is there a difference between having the field to be public vs private with a public accessor?

```
// Private field with public getter
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class TodoItem extends LightningElement {
    @track 
    _itemName = 'New Item'; 

    @api
    get itemName() {
        return this._itemName;
    }

    set itemName(value) {
        this._itemName = value;
    }
}
```

vs

```
//Public accessor
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class TodoItem extends LightningElement {
    @api 
    _itemName = 'New Item'; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LWC recommended will be:

```js
//Public accessor
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class TodoItem extends LightningElement {
    @api 
    itemName = 'New Item'
}
```

P.S: the track decorator is now [useless](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reactivity_fields)

> Like all fields as of Spring ’20, they’re reactive